# Loader not showing as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page where the user can upload a photo. I want to show a 'loading...' message whilst the photo uploads to the server but for some reason this is not working. The message shows briefly whilst the user selects a file to upload but then disappears whilst the photo uploads. I think I am misplacing the code `$('#loading').show();` in the wrong place. 
How can I make this work? Many thanks.

html

```
 <div class="loading" id="loading">
       <p>Loading...</p>
</div>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
 $('#loading').hide();
//Upload photo

$(".upload-button").on("click", function (e) {

 e.preventDefault();
       $(".file-upload").click();
        $('#loading').show();//show the loader msg
  }); 

  $('#photoimg').on('change', function() {
 $('#loading').hide(); //hide the loader msg

$("#preview").html('');

$("#imageform").ajaxForm({
target: '#preview'

  }).submit();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more your `.hide()` function that would be giving you the problem. It's showing properly, but then hiding prematurely. You need to hide it after you upload the photo, and use the `.ajaxForm` options `success` to trigger a callback function.

Ultimately you can also add a `beforeSubmit` option to `.ajaxForm` to show the loader initially.

You can read more here - http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#options-object

```
$("#imageform").ajaxForm({
    target: '#preview',
    success: hideLoader
  }).submit();
});

function hideLoader() {
   $('#loading').hide();
}
```